# Is there such a thing as an sqlite3 "function"?

Tags: function, sqlite

Suppose I have a long query in sqlite3 command line as follows:

```
select col1, col2, col3 from table1
join table2
on table2.table1_id=table1.id
join table3
on table3.table2_id=table_2.id
where col1 like "%some text%";
```

Now I would like to try this query for different wildcards like `"%some text 2%"` and `"%some text 3%"`.

I only know of two options here:

- rewriting the query multiple times in the command line (a pain in the butt)
- committing the whole thing to a script and executing with `.read test.sql`

Is there another way? Does there exist some function-like concept in sqlite3 which applies here? Ideally I would like to define the "function" and call it from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite does not support functions.

What you could do, to save you from retyping the main part of the query, is create a view:

```
create view MyView as
select col1, col2, col3 from table1
join table2
on table2.table1_id=table1.id
join table3
on table3.table2_id=table_2.id
```

Then you can add the `WHERE` clause whenever you want to execute it:

```
SELECT * FROM MyView
WHERE col1 LIKE ?;
```

Comment: Do views remain in the db after I do a `.exit` ? Also, wouldn't I be able to achieve the same behavior using a `with` statement?

Comment: @user32882 A view is a stored query. It is stored in the database, so it is reusable. A WITH clause is the starting point of a CTE. Why would you need it? Maybe explain better what you want to achieve.

Comment: I was kind of looking for something which would not persist after the connection to the database was closed. But it looks like that might not exist. I'll use views for now. Thanks.